# Moving JButtons to the left when having a background image in JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, paintcomponent

I'm pretty new to Java and working on a project. As a test for making my mainmenu, I've been experimenting with the JFrame and a picture of the powerrangers. My problem is that I've tried so many times and spent so many time on trying to get my play and my help buttons to the left of my window. I've tried making a grid of 4 and putting in an empty label but it just won't work.
This is my code:

```
package be.kdg.AngryTanksKlad;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      final Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.modernmom.com/sites/default/files/images/Power%2BRangers%2BPowerRangersMMPR.jpg"));
      final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
      frame.add(new ImagePanel(image));
      frame.setSize(800, 600);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setVisible(true);
    }
  }




@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
  private Image image;
  private boolean tile;
  private JPanel menu = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

  ImagePanel(Image image) {
    this.image = image;
    this.tile = false;
    final JButton play = new JButton("PLAY");
    final JButton help = new JButton("HELP");
    final JLabel empty = new JLabel();
  }

  menu.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));

  menu.add(empty);
  menu.add(play);
  menu.add(help);
  add(menu,BorderLayout.CENTER);
  menu.setOpaque(false);

  setVisible(true);
};

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (tile) {
        int iw = image.getWidth(this);
        int ih = image.getHeight(this);
        if (iw > 0 && ih > 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += iw) {
                for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += ih) {
                    g.drawImage(image, x, y, iw, ih, this);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 2) Provide ASCII art (or an image with a simple drawing) of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height.

Comment: ..and the code does not compile cleanly.  :(

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a java wizard yet ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

See comments in code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class SillyNAmeForAMainClassGivenIHave100CalledMain {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final Image image = new BufferedImage(400,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new ImagePanel(image));
    //frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
private Image image;
private boolean tile;
// add 5px spacing between buttons
private JPanel menu = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4,5,5));

ImagePanel(Image image) {
    super(new BorderLayout());  // default is FlowLayout!
    this.image = image;
    this.tile = false;
    final JButton play = new JButton("PLAY");
    final JButton help = new JButton("HELP");

    menu.add(play);
    menu.add(help);

    JPanel buttonConstrain = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    // pad the top of it..
    buttonConstrain.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20,5,5,5));
    buttonConstrain.setOpaque(false);
    buttonConstrain.add(menu);
    // it won't help to use a BorderLayout contraint when the default is FlowLayout!
    // LINE_START = 'left' for left-to-right locales, right for the other
    add(buttonConstrain,BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    menu.setOpaque(false);

    setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    Dimension d = null;
    if (image != null) {
        d = new Dimension(image.getWidth(this), image.getHeight(this));
    } else {
        d = new Dimension(600,400);
    }
    return d;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (tile) {
        int iw = image.getWidth(this);
        int ih = image.getHeight(this);
        if (iw > 0 && ih > 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += iw) {
                for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += ih) {
                    g.drawImage(image, x, y, iw, ih, this);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The kid made an effort to hot link an image for you and you don't even _use_ it?  WTH :D

Comment: @peeskillet I used it the first 4-5 times on my very slow connection, then got an image fetch error on it.  That's when I thought 'screw this.. `new BufferedImage(400,200,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);`'  ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It helped me a lot! :D I also adjusted the emptyBorder value of 20 to 200 to get the buttons more to the middle-left ;) I wish I could post a picture of it but i'll need a couple more influence points :D

Comment: *"I also adjusted the emptyBorder value of 20 to 200 to get the buttons more to the middle-left"*  Yes, those empty borders are *really* handy for adding white space to a GUI.  ;)  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 2):

> "My problem is that I've tried so many times and spent so many time on trying to get my play and my help buttons to the left of my window. "

1. Wrap the menu in another `JPanel`
2. Set the layout of the main `ImagePanel` to `BorderLayout`.
3. Add the new `JPanel` to `BorderLayout.WEST` of the `ImagePanel`
4. `setOpaque(false)` to the new `JPanel`

   ```
   JPanel panel = new JPanel();
   panel.setOpaque(false);
   panel.add(menu);
   setLayout(new BorderLayout());
   add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
   ```

---

Works fine

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Image image = ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.modernmom.com/sites/default/files/images/Power%2BRangers%2BPowerRangersMMPR.jpg"));
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new ImagePanel(image));
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private Image image;
    private boolean tile;
    private JPanel menu = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    ImagePanel(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        this.tile = false;
        final JButton play = new JButton("PLAY");
        final JButton help = new JButton("HELP");
        final JLabel empty = new JLabel();


        menu.setLayout(
                new GridLayout(4, 4));

        menu.add(empty);

        menu.add(play);

        menu.add(help);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        panel.add(menu);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        menu.setOpaque(false);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (tile) {
            int iw = image.getWidth(this);
            int ih = image.getHeight(this);
            if (iw > 0 && ih > 0) {
                for (int x = 0; x < getWidth(); x += iw) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < getHeight(); y += ih) {
                        g.drawImage(image, x, y, iw, ih, this);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
    }
}
```